# Attempted to use awk sqrt but only returns 0

Tags: unix, awk, sqrt

I am attempting to use the sqrt function from awk command in my script, but all it returns is 0. Is there anything wrong with my script below?

```
echo "enter number"
read root
awk 'BEGIN{ print sqrt($root) }'
```

This is my first time using the awk command, are there any mistakes that I am not understanding here?

Comment: bash  variables do not expand in single quotes.  Either change to double quotes or define an `awk` variable with `-v ` option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you can try this.

```
echo "enter number"
read root
echo "$root" | awk '{print sqrt($0)}'
```

You have to give a data input to awk. So, you can pipe 'echo'.
The BEGIN statement is to do things, like print a header...etc before
awk starts reading the input.

Comment: No. There is absolutely no need for echo and a pipe and if you DID then you **MUST** quote your shell variables unless you have a specific purpose in mind by leaving them unquoted (e.g. you need globbing wildcard expansion or compression of chains of white space or any of the other things the shell does with unquoted variables as arguments to a command) and fully understand all the caveats.

Answer (score 2):

```
$ echo "enter number"
enter number
$ read root
3
$ awk -v root="$root" 'BEGIN{ print sqrt(root) }'
1.73205
```

See [the comp.unix.shell FAQ](http://cfajohnson.com/shell/cus-faq-2.html#Q24) for the 2 correct ways to pass the value of a shell variable to an awk script.

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE : My proposed solution turns out to be potentially dangerous. See [Ed Morton's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38576209/827263) for a better solution.** I'll leave this answer here as a warning.

Because of the single quotes, `$root` is interpreted by awk, not by the shell. awk treats `root` as an uninitialized variable, whose value is the empty string, treated as `0` in a numeric context. `$root` is the `root`'th field of the current line -- in this case, as `$0`, which is the entire line. Since it's in a `BEGIN` block, there is no current line, so `$root` is the empty string -- which again is treated as `0` when passed to `sqrt()`.

You can see this by changing  your command line a bit:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN { print sqrt("") }'
0
$ echo 2 | awk '{ print sqrt($root) }'
1.41421
```

NOTE: The above is merely to show what's wrong with the original command, and how it's interpreted by the shell and by awk.

One solution is to use double quotes rather than single quotes.  The shell expands variable references within double quotes:

```
$ echo "enter number"
enter number
$ read x
2
$ awk "BEGIN { print sqrt($x) }" # DANGEROUS
1.41421
```

You'll need to be careful when doing this kind of thing.  The interaction between quoting and variable expansion in the shell vs. awk can be complicated.

**UPDATE:** In fact,  you need to be *extremely* careful. As Ed Morton points out in a comment, this method can result in arbitrary code execution given a malicious value for `$x`, which is always a risk for a value read from user input. [His answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38576209/827263) avoids that problem.

(Note that I've changed the name of your shell variable from `$root` to `$x`, since it's the number whose square root you want, not the root itself.)

Comment: `echo 2 | awk '{ print sqrt($root) }'` I guess you meant `$0` instead.

Comment: Absolutely **never** do what is suggested in this answer.

Comment: @karakfa: No, I meant what I wrote. `$root`, in that context, is equivalent to `$0`.

Comment: because it expands the value of the shell variable to become part of the awk script text the awk interpreter is reading and so can cause extremely bizarre and cryptic errors given various values of the shell variable. It's much cleaner, clearer, safer, etc. to simply set an awk variable to the value of the shell variable before the script starts and then use the awk variable within the awk script. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/38576209/1745001

Comment: As another example of an issue - try calling your awk script after setting `x='system("echo \"hello world\"")'`. Now imagine if `echo "hello world"` was `rm -rf /` or similar. Also, youd have to quote all `$` signs (e.g. `$0`) since the shell would try to expand them as positional parameters, and there's other syntactic hoops to jump through. If you absolutely HAD to let a shell variable expand as part of an awk script (which I've never seen and can't imagine happening) the safer, but still error-prone and best avoided, syntax would be `awk 'BEGIN{print sqrt('"$x"')}'`.