# Select data by euclidean distance with awk

Tags: awk, euclidean-distance

I have a big ASCII datafile and want to select the data by the Euclidean distance MINDISTANCE=5.2 to some point (x0, y0, z0)=(1,2,3).
In other words if(sqrt((x0-v2)^2+(y0-v3)^2+(z0-v4)^2))>MINDISTANCE) then print the line ($0), otherwise goto next line and test the condition ...

Input

```
#v1  v2  v3   v4
0    1    2    3        
1    4    5    6       
2    10   10   17       
3    2    3    4
4    20   20   15        
5    20   88   16     
6    20   99   17
7    20   20   22
8    1    2    3
9    10   10   20
```

Output

```
2    10   10   17       
4    20   20   15        
5    20   88   16     
6    20   99   17
7    20   20   22
9    10   10   20
```

I have seen, that the calculation of sqrt is possible in
[Attempted to use awk sqrt but only returns 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38575282/attempted-to-use-awk-sqrt-but-only-returns-0)

Otherwise the above metioned condition could be changed to 
if(((x0-v2)^2+(y0-v3)^2+(z0-v4)^2))>MINDISTANCE^2) then print the line ($0), otherwise goto next line and test the condition ...

Comment: you seem to have pseudo-code worked out, why not try it out and ask if you face problem?

Comment: agree with above comment, All you need is `awk '{ if ( ...... ) print $0 }' file [ file2 ... ]` . Good luck.

Comment: Thx the following code works, but I want to skip all lines beginning with # of the input.txt: awk '{ if ( sqrt(($2-1)**2+($3-2)**2+($4-3)**2) >5.2 ) print $0 }' input.txt

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is derived from your own pseudo-code and yields your expected outputs. I would try coding it on my own if I were you and use this as a reference.

```
BEGIN {
  min_distance = 5.2;
  x0 = 1;
  y0 = 2;
  z0 = 3;
}

{
  v2 = $2;
  v3 = $3;
  v4 = $4;

  if(sqrt((x0-v2)^2 + (y0-v3)^2 + (z0-v4)^2) > min_distance) {
    print $0;
  }
}
```

Frankly, if after a couple of attempts of coding it yourself, you still cannot come up with the appropriate `awk` code, I would spend a couple of hours learning `awk`. It's pretty straight-forward and might be worth your time.

To run it from the command line...

```
awk -f /tmp/code.awk /tmp/input.txt
```

Comment: Thanks, now I could find out why my code didn't work! How can I tell your code to skip all lines beginning with # of input.txt? In this case it is not a problem, but if v2 ... v4 are numbers, it could be a problem.

Comment: My try doesn't work: if((sqrt((x0-v2)^2 + (y0-v3)^2 + (z0-v4)^2) > min_distance) && ($1 !/#/))) {
    print $0;}

Comment: Try `awk '/^[^#]/{print}' /tmp/input.txt`. The `/^[^#]/` should be the filter for which you're looking. Prepend that regex to the `main` block of this `awk` code (i.e. the second block of code).

Comment: Is there a way to generalise this approach between all columns?

Answer (score 3):

or more briefly

```
$ awk 'NR>1 && ($2-1)^2+($3-2)^2+($4-3)^2 > 5.2^2' file

2    10   10   17
4    20   20   15
5    20   88   16
6    20   99   17
7    20   20   22
9    10   10   20
```